# Netbeans - shortcut for importing namespaces

Tags: php, html, laravel, netbeans

does anyone know if there is a key combination for importing classes in Netbeans?

[image]

By pressing enter when I get the suggestions, the namespace is imported in the method like this: 
`public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request){`

What I want to achieve instead, is to add a line `use Illuminate\Http\Request` in the top of the file. How can I do this in netbeans? I have seen it in Phpstorm.

Also, another question a little off the topic, but I have seen people generating html5 code by typing html5 and with some key combination they generate a doctype, html, head and body. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

For the first part

In newer versions of Netbeans , you can press `Ctrl+Shift+I` (`Alt+Shift+I` won't work as expected, though).

First, it searches for any smart or fully qualified instances in your file and then asks you of what types the found ones should be. It then adds fully qualified use statements to the top of your file and changes existing instances in the source to unqualified.

For the second part
You have to use a plugin called [Emmet](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48315/emmet)